# Getting error TS2694: Namespace 'angular' has no exported member 'ui', when loading angular-ui-router

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, sharepoint-framework

I'am trying to setup multi-page app with angular, and i tried to follow the sample code and this [link](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/build-multi-page-sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-angular/).

When i install angular-ui-router, by npm command : npm install angular-ui-router -s , i get an warning message, se pic :
[image]

And on this [link](https://ui-router.github.io/blog/uirouter-scoped-packages/), you can find info about using it as scoped package.

In package.json, simply replace the old npm package with the scoped @uirouter package. For example, if you currently depend on angular-ui-router.

```
 "dependencies": {
"angular-ui-router": "latest",
"ui-router-visualizer": "latest",
```

}

replace the package name with the scoped @uirouter package:

```
 "dependencies": {
"@uirouter/angularjs": "latest",
"@uirouter/visualizer": "latest",
```

}

By doing what is described above, nothing happens, still same error:
[image]

Googling dont help so much, there are not so many samples/tutorials to rellay on. Alot of the blogs and samples are old, and there no straight forward explanation on how to fix this issue.

Any suggestion how i can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprising that no one did answer on this issue......

Finally i managed to figure it out by my self. And the problem was that i installed @uirouter/angular without removing "angualr-ui-router" package.

When you get Warning message:
[image]

Do not install @uirouter/angular before removing the "angular-ui-router" package by command: npm rm angular-ui-router --save

And then replace dependencies from:

> "dependencies": {
>   "angular-ui-router": "latest"

to

> "dependencies": {
>   "@uirouter/angularjs": "latest"

finally run command: npm install

-gulp clean
--gulp build

These steps fixed the issue....